# How deep does inheritance have to go before considering other options?

Tags: oop, inheritance

I've read numerous articles ([1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/137687/why-is-subclassing-too-much-bad-and-hence-why-should-we-use-prototypes-to-do-aw/137705),[2](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073649/core-java/why-extends-is-evil.html)) about the pitfalls of inheritance and the other options that you can consider.

I've never understood deep inheritance hierarchy. How deep does an inheritance have to go before you consider other options?

Comment: "'Too much' is a judgement call" - first link's top answer starts with that. There can't be a hard and fast number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, most well-designed object-oriented classes should be at level one, ie, they should not extend any other class (not counting a fundamental base class such as `java.lang.Object`). Such classes should be declared as "final" (`final` in Java, `sealed` in C#).

A minority of classes will be designed as *base classes*. They will typically have subclasses at level two in the inheritance tree. Usually, they have a number of `protected` methods, some of which are overridable (`virtual`, non-`final`) and others not (`final`, non-`virtual`). For example, a class implementing the Template Method design pattern will normally make the template method itself non-overridable.

Any additional subclasses (at level three and beyond) should be rare. I would recommend to avoid anything beyond a depth of three, unless you are using an existing library such as Java Swing which was designed to require deeper inheritance levels (which doesn't mean the design of Swing is good).

In any case, any class which is not meant to be used as a base class should be declared as `final`/`sealed`, in order to prevent or discourage inheritance abuse.

These recommendations are in line with recent books that discuss OO and API design, such as "Effective Java", "Practical API Design", and "API Design for C++".